# How to write a csv file into an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, csv, getline, opencsv

I'm trying to read a csv file and write it into an array. I have an error in getline. the error is:
no instance of overloaded function "getline" matches the argument list.
what's wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    ifstream Input("M.A.csv");
    int index = 0;
    const int Num = 57;
    int shift_counter = 0;
    char Data[Num][6];

    if (Input.is_open()) {

        cout << '\n' << '\t' << "Anslyzing file..." << endl << '\n';

        while (Input) {
            
            getline(Input, Data[index]);
            cout << Data[index][2];
            cout << ++index << endl;
            if (++index == Num) {
                index = 0;
                shift_counter++;
                cout << '\n' << '\t' << "*** shift_counter is :" << shift_counter << '\n' << '\t';
            }//if (++index == Num)
        }//while (Input)
         /*for (int i = 1,j=1; i <= Num ,j<=6 ; i++, j++) {
         Data[i][j]=
         }*/
    }//if (Input.is_open())
    else {

        cout << '\n' << '\t' << "No file has been opened" << endl << '\n';
    }//else


    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

The type char has no matter for getline, so why I can't getline?

Comment: You probably want the C++ tag as well.

Answer (score 0):

The [function getline(](https://cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/)) expects the second argument to be a `std::string`, but you provide a `char` array. There is no overloaded instance with those types.

Comment: I already tested it but the error was not fixed.

Comment: @Jasper what did you test? This solving this requires a refactoring of the code to used strings instead of character arrays.